# Next.js catch-all routes for nested structure

Tags: next.js, url-routing

I'm trying to implement route e.g /page/news/title/tab and following folder struture for it, but I got the error: You cannot define a route with the same specificity as a optional catch-all route. So how to build folder structure in right way?

```
   pages/
    news/
     [[...rest]].js
     index.js
   index.js
```

Answer (score 3):

The route `news/index.js` conflicts with `news/[[...rest]].js` because it's an [*optional* catch all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes).

> Catch all routes can be made optional by including the parameter in
> double brackets (`[[...slug]]`).
>
> For example, `pages/post/[[...slug]].js` will match `/post`, `/post/a`,
> `/post/a/b`, and so on.
>
> The main difference between catch all and optional catch all routes is
> that with optional, the route without the parameter is also matched
> (`/post` in the example above).

---

You can either remove the `news/index.js` route, as the optional catch all route already matches it.

```
pages/
├─ news/
│   └─ [[...rest]].js
└─ index.js
```

Or, make the catch all route non-optional by including the parameter in single brackets (`[...rest]`).

```
pages/
├─ news/
│   ├─ [...rest].js
│   └─ index.js
└─ index.js
```

Comment: I have a question about nested catch-all routes. I want to know how to make a page a "catch-all" without making it a dynamic route. I only see docs and references for dynamic catch-all routes. 

How do I make the pages/user-dasshboard/requests/index.js page the default page for the pages/user-dashboard route?

Comment: @Avery-DanteHinds You can use [`rewrites`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites) to map a route to a different one.